# I need to extract all id values with casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```
id = casper.evaluate(function() { 
  return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("image"), 
  function(e) {return e.getElementById();});});

this.echo(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

**--Update--**

If you want get elements containing a specific `class` just use a helper function to scrape the elements you are looking for.

Example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var ids = [];

function getIdsByClassValue() {
  // use your selector here eg. '.image'.
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(elems, function (e) {
    // change to the attribute you are looking for.
    return e.getAttribute('value')
  });
}

casper.start('https://www.google.com/');

casper.then(function () {
  ids = this.evaluate(getIdsByClassValue);
});

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo('\n - ' + ids.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

You can use `getElementsAttribute` to do that.

> [.getElementsAttribute](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsattribute)
>
> **Signature**: getElementsAttribute(String selector, String attribute)
>
> *Retrieves the values of an attribute on each element matching the provided selector:*

Here is an example.

```
var ids = [];

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://google.com/', function() {
    this.wait(1000, function() {
        ids = this.getElementsAttribute('*', 'id')
          .filter(function(id) {
              return id.length > 0;
          })
    });
});

casper.then( function() {
  this.echo('\n - ' + ids.join('\n - ')).exit();
})

casper.run();
```

Comment: I want to specify by unique class name <div id = 111 class = "image"> <div id = 222 class = "image">

Comment: I have made an edit. You would just have to change the `querySelectorAll` and pass in your css class name eg. `'.image'`, you also want to change the `getAttribute` to the attribute you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`return e.getElementById();` does obviously not make any sense, because [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a function that expect one argument and is only available on the `document`.

It seems you want to return the [`id` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id):

```
var ids = casper.evaluate(function() { 
  return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("image"), function(e) {
    return e.id;
  });
});

this.echo(ids);
```